# How do I create repeated structures in a Keras network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create an autoencoder network in Keras to learn the dynamics of a system I'm analyzing but am not sure how to do it. As you can see below, `x` is encoded by `phi` into a lower dimensional `z`-space. The `A` network computes the derivative of `z` and then `psi` decodes the derivative back up into the full dimensional space. In addition to having `psi` decode `z_dot` to `x_dot`, I would like to add the constraint that `psi` also decodes `z` back into `x`. You can see in the diagram below that this can be done by repeating the decoder structure.

[image]

I know you can create Keras networks with multiple input/output tensors, but I am not sure if it's possible to repeat my decoder structure like I have shown? In this sense the decoder will learn from two data sets simultaneously. Is this possible? If so, how could I implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the key is to call the "psi-constructor" once and plug it multiple times to functional flows, as opposed to instantiating "psi" twice, so that there is a single set of weight variables shared between the "two" psi's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you'd want to create an architecture called psi. Then instantiate it once, and reuse that as a layer in your network. The idea is to share the weights (use the exact same layer twice). So you might have:

```py
def create_psi():
    # define your psi architecture here
    return psi

def decoder():
    psi = create_psi()
    X_input = Input(dims) #dims are the dimensions of z
    Z_dot = A(X_input) #Using whatever layer A is
    X_dot = psi(Z_dot)
    X = psi(X_input)
    decoder = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=[X_dot, X])
    return decoder

# Instantiate decoder model here, compile with appropriate loss, etc.
```